# Select no muestra todos los valores en C# y ASP.NET

Tags: c#, select, asp, dropdownlist

Tengo el siguiente código en ASP.NET.

```
     <div id="selector_tip_equipo" class="col-sm-9">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="TipoEquipo" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="" Text="Selecciona..."></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Text="Profesional"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Text="Base"></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
      </div>
```

Luego con el valor que selecciono este select lo guardo en la base de datos, y luego lo quiero mostrar en una tabla de esta forma:

```
          for (i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
                {
               celda = new TableCell();

                DropDownList selector = new DropDownList();
                selector.ID = "select" + lista[i].Codigo;
                selector.Attributes.Add("onchange", "GuardaTipoLiga('select" + lista[i].Codigo + "', " + i.ToString() + ");");
                for (j = 0; j < lista.Count; j++)
                {
                    selector.Items.Add(new ListItem(lista[j].WidgetElegido));
                }

                if (lista[i].WidgetElegido.Length > 0)
                    selector.Items.FindByText(lista[i].WidgetElegido).Selected = true;
                else
                    selector.SelectedIndex = 0;
                tipo_liga = tipo_liga + lista[i].WidgetElegido + "+";
                celda.Controls.Add(selector);
                fila.Cells.Add(celda);

                  }
```

El problema es que ese `select` lo guardo mediante un botón y por eso creo id, atributos que llama a la función en JS y demás.

Pero el `select` no me saca todos los valores del desplegable. Solo saca del select en asp.net los valores que hayas insertado en esa tabla. Es decir, si solo has insertado un valor con profesional, luego no puedo cambiar ese valor a base, ya que no hay ningún valor insertado que se llame base luego el `select` no lo despliega.

Me he explicado? Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Lo valores del DropDownList `ID="TipoEquipo"` van a ser siempre los mismos?,o sea, Profesional, Base, etc...

Comment: Sí, así es. De momento no van a cambiar.